# How do I break on exception for Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web?

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I can't seem to find the dialog box to config the IDE so that I can break on all exceptions.

According to this article, I can add it in, but it fails in step 5, because there is no Exceptions command.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d14azbfh.aspx

Where has it gone?

Comment: I would really like to know also. I can not believe they would take out this feature. I might have to go back to 2010 express.